# "may contain sugar" vs "can contain sugar"

Tags: modal-verbs

Consider the following self-made sentences:

> 1. Please note that some of the foods over there may contain processed sugar.
> 2. Please note that some of the foods over there can contain processed sugar.

According Practical English by Michael Swan, the second one should not be said. I am not very sure about this argument.

I suppose that it is fine to say "something can be harmful"; if so, why is it not fine to say "something can contain a harmful ingredient", but "something may contain a harmful ingredient"?

Comment: In this context, *can* means *is capable of*. But, also in this context, it would be pointless to put *can* on a label—because food is *capable* of containing anything at all. It would be just as valid to say *this food **can** contain arsenic*. The sense required here is one of *possibility* in the specific context of ***likelihood***, not *capability*. So, you have to use *may*. Another word that could be used is *might*.

Comment: @JasonBassford I see, but could'nt "can" be used to talk about the possibility as I mentioned in the question like, "this thing can hurt you, so be careful when working with it"

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's possible. That's certainly one dictionary sense of the word. And it's used in just that way in the *this thing can hurt you* sense. But it's not used that way when it comes to food labels. (Although *smoking can kill you* is used on cigarette labels.) If you want, you can call this an arbitrary way we've come to use the language. Even though *can* does also have that *possible* sense, it's just not applied in that way to food labels. I don't know why …

Answer (score 2):

The difference as I see it is the same as @Jason Bassford was referring to:
*Can* in this context indicates something very weak -- it indicates that something is technically not impossible, but gives no indication of whether or not that something can be expected.  It is completely neutral about likelihood.
*May*, on the other hand, indicates that there is some significant extent to which that something is to be expected.  It indicates that there is a certain likelihood, enough so that a warning is warranted.